# Nesting MDX content

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I have a mdx file and using a component in that

```
---
title: Topic 1
---
<Test>[link](https://google.com/)</Test>
```

using my code the content of `Test` component is rendering as simple text but I want to render them as mdx as well

```
import * as React from "react";
import { MDXRenderer } from "gatsby-plugin-mdx";
import { MDXProvider } from "@mdx-js/react";
import { Test } from "./test";


export default function ({ docName, title, body, slug }) {
  const shortcodes = { Test };
  return (
     <MDXProvider components={shortcodes}>
        <MDXRenderer>{body}</MDXRenderer>
     </MDXProvider>
  );
}
```

and `Test` component is a simple component that only return content of children prop
`export default Test = ({children}) => children`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a markdown interpreter like [`markdown-to-jsx`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/markdown-to-jsx) and the implementation is quite similar:

```
export default Test = ({children}) => <Markdown>{children}</Markdown>
```

In addition if you want to keep your `MDXProvider` check the structure of the MDX and add some empty line spaces (`\n`) like:

```
<Test>

[link](https://google.com/)

</Test>
```

Comment: nesting `MDXRenderer` component generating an error. and also using `markdown-to-jsx` has some limitations (it pars md not mdx).

Comment: i fixed the problem. to render content of `Test` components as mdx I only have to put an empty line before and after of that